# how to Create Android mobile Application using "Android + App Engine"?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I want to develop Android Mobile Application using "Android + App Engine". I don't have any idea about App Engine. so please Suggest me how to Create Application using "Android + App Engine". If any buddy have demo Code or link related to "Android + App Engine" Application Development please Share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some info from Google I/O 2011:

http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/

and the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U